# How to get the ID of the row a command button is in (in MS Access Detail Section)

Tags: ms-access, button

I have an MS Access 2003 form with a datasheet detail.  I want to add "Print" button to each row which will open a detail report for that row.

Inside the `Click` handler, how do I access the ID of the row the button was in so I can pass it to the report?

```
Private Sub btnPrint_Click()
         DoCmd.OpenReport "rptPrintDetails", acViewPreview, "", "Id=" & '<==== what goes here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Value` property of the ID control on the form .  Or, since the `Value` property is the default property, you can just use the name of the control.

For example, if you have a textbox control named "txtID", your code would say

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptPrintDetails", acViewPreview, "", "Id=" & Me.txtID
```